# Как проверить подпись apk и сравнить ее с подписью установленного приложения?

Tags: android, java

Всем привет! Подскажите, возможно ли проверить каким ключом подписано установленное приложение и сверить с подписью скачанного apk?

Если это возможно, то как это сделать?

Это требуется, чтобы при совпадении подписей, apk заменяло существующее приложение и не требовалось удаление, существующего, чтобы не терять данные

Comment: Chekey от guardian project, а нужно это для того, чтобы дополненное во время скачивания mitm атакой приложение не сифонило. Хотя ходят слухи что md5 на данный момент ничего не значит и меняется в любое время по желанию взломщика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря, не понял зачем тебе это. Ведроид ведь и так за тебя все это делает.

А apk`шку, подписанную один раз ключемA и выложенную в Google Play, второй раз подписать другим ключемВ и выложить не получится - Google ругаться будет.

**UPDATE**:

[Как взять подпись по имени пакета](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578871/android-how-to-get-app-signature).
Имена пакетов правда для обоих файлов буду совпадать, нужно как то из установленного приложения взять подпись из apk не уставновленного, что то гугл мне ничего хорошего по этому поводу не рассказал

[Как установить apk по его пути](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android). На сколько я понял, все равно будет спрашивать про permissions

Comment: о Google Play я знаю, делается это для своего "менеджера обновления"  для конкретного приложения на кастомном недоандроиде, на котором нет приложения google play. По факту, это приложение никогда не будет выложено в маркет

Comment: Да, правильно :)
Только я уже сам это сделал, но спасибо :)

Comment: пожалуйста)